# What modes are supported by ADS1299 for powerline noise reduction, and where to connect them?

Tags: arduino, amplifier, adc, dac, texas-instruments

[image]

I am using this ADS1299 Frontend Board with a Rp2040 Pico, my SPI connections and lib work fine, but I am facing problems in understanding how to use a refference electrode, I am getting good signals but I want to remove/reduce the  powerline noise from my sEMG's.
Can anyone help me with the following doubts:

1. What all different modes can I use to reduce powerline/AC noise ?
2. I want to use only one reffence electrode, somewhere near my elbow, which pin I need to connect it, and is there any other RC circuit/ Filter/ or any other circuit between the ADS1299 and the refference electrode ?

> I am getting signals form 8 channels, and need only one more electrode as a refference electrode, which will be connected to the user's arm to reduce poweline/AC noise, where to connect it, and is there any other component or circuit between the ADS1299 chip and the reffernce electrode which I should implement in my custom circuit which I am trying to build nothing else.

Here is my initial settings for the registers:

```
  ADS.verbose = true;      // Enable verbose mode for serial feedback 
  ADS.RESET();             // Send RESET command to default all registers
  ADS.SDATAC();            // Exit Read Data Continuous mode to communicate with ADS

  ADS.WREG(CONFIG1,0b00000101); // Write to CONFIG1 register, set data rate to 256 SPS
  ADS.WREG(CONFIG2,0b11010101); // Write to CONFIG2 register
  ADS.WREG(CONFIG3,0b11001100); // Write to CONFIG3 register, enable bias measurement and internal reference buffer

  // Write to CHxSET registers, enable all channels and connect them to normal electrode input
  ADS.WREG(CH1SET,0b00000000); // Enable channel 1
  ADS.WREG(CH2SET,0b00000000); // Enable channel 2
  ADS.WREG(CH3SET,0b00000000); // Enable channel 3
  ADS.WREG(CH4SET,0b00000000); // Enable channel 4
  ADS.WREG(CH5SET,0b00000000); // Enable channel 5
  ADS.WREG(CH6SET,0b00000000); // Enable channel 6
  ADS.WREG(CH7SET,0b00000000); // Enable channel 7
  ADS.WREG(CH8SET,0b00000000); // Enable channel 8

  // Write to BIAS_SENSP and BIAS_SENSN registers, select all channels for bias drive signal
  ADS.WREG(BIAS_SENSP,0b11111111); 
  ADS.WREG(BIAS_SENSN,0b11111111);

  // Write to LOFF_SENSP and LOFF_SENSN registers, enable lead-off detection on all channels
  ADS.WREG(LOFF_SENSP,0b11111111);
  ADS.WREG(LOFF_SENSN,0b11111111);

  ADS.WREG(CONFIG4,0x02); // Write to CONFIG4 register
  
  ADS.RREGS(0x00,0x17);     // Read all registers starting at ID and ending at CONFIG4

  ADS.RDATAC();            // Enter Read Data Continuous mode
  ADS.START();             // Start the ADS1299 device
```

[Here is the link for the mannual which I am using](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau443b/slau443b.pdf?ts=1702729744328&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FADS1299)

Please help

Following are my SPI connections [Green Highlighted]

[image]

Comment: Are you able to take your measurements with an integration time equal to an integer number of power line cycles? This is a very effective way to eliminate power line noise, as the effect of the positive half-cycle will be mostly cancelled out by the negative half-cycle.

Comment: @Hearth , thanks for replying, can you explain a bit more, I am very new to this, I just want to use a reffernce electrode, know what modes ADS1299 chip supports and lastly how to connect the reffence electrode to teh ADS1299 chip [ like is there any other component or circuit /filter in between them ? ]

Comment: I don't know anything about your situation, I'm afraid. But I know that high precision measurements often integrate over PLCs to cancel out noise.

Comment: @Hearth can you explain a bit more, or give some guide or refference weblinks for which method are you suggesting, it would be really helpfull, and thanks for replying.

Comment: Did you read the front-end block diagram on the page 14 of the linked document?